# Centrar imagen de fondo

Tags: php, html

Mi código HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Biblioteca</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background: url('Carnetsocio.png') no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
    
        <header>
            <h1 align="center">Socio</h1>
        </header>
    
        <form action="tablasocio.php" method="post"><br>
    
            <center>
    
            DNI:<br>
            <input type="text" name="DNI" value="" placeholder="DNI"><br>
            NOMBRE:<br>
            <input type="text" name="NOMBRE" value="" placeholder="NOMBRE"><br>
            CADUCIDAD:<br>
            <input type="date" name="CADUCIDAD" value="" ><br><br>
    
    
             <div>
            <label for="condiciones">¿Acepta las <a href="socio.html">condiciones</a> por las cuales, acepta ser socio/a de la biblioteca?</label><input type="checkbox" name="condiciones" />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
            </div>
    
                <td align="center "> <input type="reset" name="Borrar"  id="Borrar" value="Borrar" /></td>
                <td align="center"> <input type="submit" name="enviar"  id="enviar" value="Enviar" /></td>
    
            </center>
    
        </form>
    
                <div style="text-align:center;padding:1em 0;"> <h4><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/es/city/3117735"><span style="color:gray;">Hora actual en</span><br />Madrid, España</a></h4> <iframe src="https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/clock-widget-iframe-v2?language=es&size=small&timezone=Europe%2FMadrid" width="100%" height="90" frameborder="0" seamless></iframe> </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Mi código PHP

```
    <?php  
        
        $dni= $_POST["DNI"];
        $nombre=$_POST["NOMBRE"];
        $caducidad=$_POST["CADUCIDAD"];
        
        $db_host="localhost";
        $db_usuario="root";
        $db_contra=NULL ;
        $db_nombre="biblioteca";
        
        
        
        $connexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
        
        if( mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
        
              echo "Hubo un problema con la base de datos error al conectar";
        
              exit() ;
          }
        
       mysqli_select_db($connexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la Base de datos");
        
       mysqli_set_charset($connexion,"utf8");
        
        
      $instruccion_SQL = "INSERT INTO Socio VALUES('$dni','','$nombre','$caducidad')";
        
       $resultado = mysqli_query($connexion,$instruccion_SQL);
        
       if($resultado == FALSE){
         echo "error en la consulta";
       } else {
         echo "Registro guardado<br><br>";
         echo "<table><tr><td>dni:$dni</td></tr>";
         echo "<tr><td>nombre:$nombre</td></tr>" ;
         echo "<tr><td>caducidad:$caducidad</td> </tr></table>" ;    
        }        
        mysqli_close($connexion);    
    
          if( isset( $_POST['condiciones'] ) ) {
           echo  "El cliente aceptó las condiciones";
      } else {
           echo  "El cliente no aceptó las condiciones";
      }
    ?>
```

Estoy intentado poner una imagen de fondo para un carnet de socio que he hecho así de improvisada para un proyecto de clase y no logro introducir el código para centrarla.

He vuelto al punto de background porque me había antes cargado el código y mejor prevenir que curar con el php.

¿Alguien me echa un cable para que quede el resultado centralizado como si hubieses rellenado el carnet de socio?

La verdad es que me gustaría un resultado elegante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el estilo de body puedes poner:

```
background: url(Carnetsocio.png) no-repeat; background-size: contains; background-position:center center
```

El tamaño de background-size lo he puesto a contains, si poner cover siempre va a ocupar todo el bloque, entonces el centrado no tendría sentido, al menos según veo yo.
Y ojo, se recomienda usar reglas de estilos CSS en lugar de style.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo parecido a esto. Un formulario el cual cuando lo rellene se te envié para crear el carnet.

**Nota :** El carnet no tiene datos porque no se ha introducido nada en el formulario.

### Carnet.php

```css
body {
    /* La imagen de fondo se reescala automÃ¡ticamente con el cambio del ancho de ventana del navegador */
    background-size: cover;
    /* Para dejar la imagen de fondo centrada, vertical y horizontalmente */
    background-position: center center;
    /* Para que la imagen de fondo no se repita */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* La imagen se fija en la ventana de visualizaciÃ³n para que la altura de la imagen no supere a la del contenido */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* Ubicacion de la imagen */
    background-image: url(2.jpg);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    font-weight: bold;
}


h1 {
    text-align: center;
    

}

table {
        color: white;
        background-color: black;

}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}


p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Carnet de Socio</title>
    <link href="index2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
        if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){

        }

        $dni = $_POST['dni'];
        $foto = $_POST['imagen'];
        $ldni = $_POST['LetraDni'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
        $fnac = $_POST['fnac'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $direc = $_POST['direc'];
        $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
        $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
        $gener = $_POST['gener'];
        $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
        $dia = $_POST['dia'];
        $mes = $_POST['mes'];

        if ($pass1!=$pass2) {
            header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: ./error.php");
            exit;

        }
     ?>
     <center>
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <h1>Carnet del Videoclub</h1>
     <br/>
     <table >
        <tr>
            <td>DNI del Socio : </td>
            <td><?php echo $_POST['dni']; ?><?php echo $_POST['LetraDni']; ?></td>
            <center>
            <td ROWSPAN="4" ><div align="right"><img width="50%" height="50%" src="<?php echo $_POST['imagen']; ?>"></div></td>
            </center>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre : </td>
            <td><?php echo $_POST['nombre']; ?></td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Apellidos : </td>
            <td><?php echo $_POST['apellidos']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fecha de Nacimiento : </td>
            <td><?php echo $_POST['dia']; ?>/<?php echo $_POST['mes']; ?>/<?php echo $_POST['fnac']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Direccion : </td>
            <td COLSPAN="2"><?php echo $_POST['direc']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Telefono : </td>
            <td COLSPAN="2"><?php echo $_POST['telefono']; ?></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     </center>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
    /* La imagen de fondo se reescala automÃ¡ticamente con el cambio del ancho de ventana del navegador */
    background-size: cover;
    /* Para dejar la imagen de fondo centrada, vertical y horizontalmente */
    background-position: center center;
    /* Para que la imagen de fondo no se repita */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* La imagen se fija en la ventana de visualizaciÃ³n para que la altura de la imagen no supere a la del contenido */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* Ubicacion de la imagen */
    background-image: url(2.jpg);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    font-weight: bold;
}


h1 {
    text-align: center;
    

}

table {
        color: white;
        background-color: black;

}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}


p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Formulario de Carlos</title>
    <link href="index2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h2>Formulario para ser socio del videoclub de Javi</h2>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    <form method="post" action="carnet.php" type="POST" enctype="multipart/formdata" >
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="num">DNI : </label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['dni']; ?>" name="dni"size="10"/>
                    <select name="LetraDni" id="LetraDni">
                        <option>T</option>
                        <option>R</option>
                        <option>W</option>
                        <option>A</option>
                        <option>G</option>
                        <option>M</option>
                        <option>Y</option>
                        <option>F</option>
                        <option>P</option>
                        <option>B</option>
                        <option>N</option>
                        <option>J</option>
                        <option>Z</option>
                        <option>S</option>
                        <option>Q</option>
                        <option>V</option>
                        <option>H</option>
                        <option>L</option>
                        <option>C</option>
                        <option>K</option>
                        <option>E</option>
                    </select>
                    Pon tu foto para el carnet de Socio :
                </td>
                <td><input type="file" name="imagen" value="<?php echo "<img src='uploads/$file_name' >";?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="num">Nombre : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['nombre']; ?>" name="nombre"size="8"/></td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="num">Apellidos : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['apellidos']; ?>" name="apellidos"size="8"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="num">Fecha de Nacimiento : </label></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="dia" id="dia">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                        <option>13</option>
                        <option>14</option>
                        <option>15</option>
                        <option>16</option>
                        <option>17</option>
                        <option>18</option>
                        <option>19</option>
                        <option>20</option>
                        <option>21</option>
                        <option>22</option>
                        <option>23</option>
                        <option>24</option>
                        <option>25</option>
                        <option>26</option>
                        <option>27</option>
                        <option>28</option>
                        <option>29</option>
                        <option>30</option>
                        <option>31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="mes" id="mes">
                        <option>Enero</option>
                        <option>Febrero</option>
                        <option>Marzo</option>
                        <option>Abril</option>
                        <option>Mayo</option>
                        <option>Junio</option>
                        <option>Julio</option>
                        <option>Agosto</option>
                        <option>Septiembre</option>
                        <option>Octubre</option>
                        <option>Noviembre</option>
                        <option>Diciembre</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['fnac']; ?>" name="fnac"size="8"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="num">Contraseña : </label></td>
                <td><input type="password" value="<?php echo $_POST['pass1']; ?>" name="pass1"size="8"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="num">Repite la Contraseña : </label></td>
                <td><input type="password" value="<?php echo $_POST['pass2']; ?>" name="pass2"size="8"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="num">Telefono : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['telefono']; ?>" name="telefono"size="8"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="num">Direccion : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['direc']; ?>" name="direc"size="8"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="num">Generos Favoritos : </label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drama" name="drama"/>Dramatico
                    <input type="checkbox" id="humor" name="humor"/>Comedia
                    <input type="checkbox" id="terror" name="terror"/>Terror
                    <input type="checkbox" id="romantico" name="romantico"/>Romantico
                    <input type="checkbox" id="accion" name="accion"/>Accion
                    <input type="checkbox" id="fantasia" name="fantasia"/>Fantasia
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr><td><label for="formpago">Forma de Pago : </label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="transf" name="formpago"/>Transferencia
                    <input type="radio" id="metal" name="formpago"/>Metalico
                    <input type="radio" id="tercer" name="formpago"/>En Negro
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><label for="comentario">Comentarios</label><br/>
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="100%" value="<?php echo $_POST['comentario']; ?>" name="comentario"></textarea>
                </td>       
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </center>

    

</body>
</html>
```

***Por ejemplo :*** Introduzco unos datos en el formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de Darle al botón enviar mostrara algo parecido a esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Nota Importante :*** Esto es un ejemplo general debes adaptarlo a tu código según tus necesidades.

Te dejo un video mío de [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SCbIcZHsYo) sobre ejemplo que puede hacer este formulario.

[<kbd>Probar código en mi Hosting</kbd>](https://javiergraya.000webhostapp.com/Formulario/formu.php)